# Disable the 'requirement' to double click an unfocused window when clicking on a menustrip

Tags: c#, winforms

Sorry about the weird title, I'm currently playing around with WinForms and I'm wondering if there is any way to make it so that you don't have to 'double-click' the window to activate an item in a menustrip when the window is unfocused?

Currently if the window is unfocused I first have to click on the window to give it focus and then click once again on the menustrip item even if my mouse was hovering above the menustrip item from the start.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try putting this function in your Form class:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    int WM_PARENTNOTIFY = 0x0210;
    if (!this.Focused && m.Msg == WM_PARENTNOTIFY) {
        // Make this form auto-grab the focus when menu/controls are clicked
        this.Activate();
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: this seems to work with ToolStrip but not with a MenuStrip

Answer (score 0):

The method in @Detmar's answer will focus the window when the window is destroyed (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh454920(v=vs.85).aspx). That can cause issues if you have multiple windows in your application and you are exiting. Here is one that won't trigger when you are disposing windows:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const int WM_PARENTNOTIFY = 0x0210;
        if (!this.Focused && m.Msg == WM_PARENTNOTIFY)
        {
            const int WM_CREATE = 0x0001;
            const int WM_DESTROY = 0x0002;
            const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
            const int WM_MBUTTONDOWN = 0x0207;
            const int WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204;
            const int WM_XBUTTONDOWN = 0x020B;
            const int WM_POINTERDOWN = 0x0246;

            int type = (int)(0xFFFF & (long)m.WParam);
            switch (type)
            {
                case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                case WM_MBUTTONDOWN:
                case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
                case WM_XBUTTONDOWN:
                case WM_POINTERDOWN:
                    // Make this form auto-grab the focus when menu/controls are clicked
                    this.Activate();
                    break;
                case WM_DESTROY:
                case WM_CREATE:
                    //do nothing
                    break;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```