# Run exe from inside windows form, and use the boundaries of that windows form

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I want to run an exe or two from inside a windows form.

I want to be able to keep the exe inside the boundary of the actual form I create.

Comment: I think you're asking for an MDI framework, where the children are other EXEs.  That is going to be exceedingly ugly to pull off.

Answer (score 1):

This requires a bit of Windows API trickery. The technique is called "Subclassing a Window" and you can read more about it on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633570(v=vs.85).aspx) - scroll down a bit to find the relevant section.

Ryan looks like he got most of the way there in C# answering his own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524519/subclass-a-parentform-wndproc-from-a-control), but states that he didn't solve it completely. I have done this very successfully using C code similar to that you see in the MSDN article.

It is not explicitly stated in the MSDN article, but it is a best practice to reset WndProc back to it's orginal value when done (e.g. when your app exits). You'll see in Ryan's code that he does do this.