# Why two time click is required to click ToolStripMenuItem?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a winform application running , i added one more winform one top of this application which will pass some datas to the the application. After passing the datas to the application, Save button will be enabled to save data in to application. The save button is toolstripmenuitem. One issue i am facing is when the newly added form is still there, i need to click two times to save ie first click will not click properly . Or if i close the newly added winform then save click will happen first time itself or if i click any part of the exisitng application ie focus will be there ,then also first click will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty answered your own question: new form takes focus when got added. So it is up to you how to handle this "by design" issue:

- bring main form to front after the other form has passed the data;
- close the other form altogether;
- show a descriptive message so that the users try to save knowing they
  can save;
- ...
- PROFIT!

;)

Comment: we cannot close the other form and and bring main form front, we did based on user requirement.Can we put a check like whether focus is there or not? and that time only enable save button

Comment: Well you can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057473/disable-the-requirement-to-double-click-an-unfocused-window-when-clicking-on-a

Comment: Correct answer: Kleinux

Answer (score 13):

Adding this method override to the form containing your tool strip should take care of it.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    const int WM_PARENTNOTIFY = 0x0210;
    if (m.Msg == WM_PARENTNOTIFY)
    {
        if (!Focused)
            Activate();
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

The tool strip is performing the Activate call only, so by handling it ourselves it will perform the Click event

Comment: Execllent!  This saved much frustration.

Answer (score 0):

When you enable the save button wich you at some point have to do in your main form, call Focus() on it. That way focus is given back to the main form and the user can perform one click to save